# Loading text onto a webpage using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Which is the best way to load text into a webpage using ASP.NET

I have 3 records in a MS SQL database table.  Each record would correspond to a paragraph in a webpage.

Table:

[image]

The HTML code for the About us page would look like this (note I put the corresponding paragraphs) :

```
<div id="content-1b">
    <div id="content-1-1b">
        </div>
    <div id="content-1-2b"><p class="none">paragraph 1</p>
                           <p class="nonetop">paragraph 2</p>
        </div>
</div>

<div id="content-3b"><p class="nonetop">paragraph 3</p>
    </div>
```

Regards,
Tea

Comment: It will be C#.  I want to access the data via ado.net.  Each paragraph corresponds to a record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting your divs or paragraph tags as runat="server" with an ID will allow you to access innerhtml/text

HTML:

```
<div id="content-1b">
    <div id="content-1-1b">
        </div>
    <div id="content-1-2b"><p class="none" id="p1" runat="server">paragraph 1</p>
                           <p id="p2" runat="server" class="nonetop">paragraph 2</p>
        </div>
</div>

<div id="content-3b"><p id="p3" runat="server" class="nonetop">paragraph 3</p>
    </div>
```

Running code like: (assuming your content is in a datatable and that you want the first item (0) from each row)

```
For each row as Datarow in dt
     p1.InnerHtml += Row.Item(0).ToString
Next
```

Will loop through your datatable, get the first column from each row and append the text to the paragraph tag.

**Update:**

For Single Content

If your SQL returns 3 rows, 1 for each area you want to fill simply do:

Assuming dt is the datatable you are filling and that the first column of each row is your content.

```
p1.InnerHTML = dt.rows(0).Item(0)
p2.InnerHTML = dt.rows(1).Item(0)
p3.InnerHTML = dt.rows(2).Item(0)
```

Comment: Basically my problem, paragraph 1 text is in record 1, paragraph 2 text is in record 2, etc.

Comment: So I return 3 row, store them in a datatable, then use the InnerHTML to read into each <div>.  Looks like a workable solutions.  I will get coding this.

Comment: You innerHTML syntax is incorrect, but I'll mark you because you got me a general answer.  Go here for answer >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819017/trying-to-read-items-from-a-datatable-into-a-webpage

Comment: @TeaDrinkingGeek it was written in VB.net as I didn't remember seeing a tag of a language when I wrote it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Declare these Divs as server controls by giving an unique Id a d runat=server so that you can access the object back in code behind.

These divs are equavilent to HTMLGenericControl so you can just say divid.innerHTML = content.

Or you can also use a repeater and bind to your div

Comment: Would you know of examples of this I can view?

Comment: Google is your friend.  I agree a Repeater might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm only loading in 3 pieces of text all at once.  Is repeater what I really need?

Comment: if its only 3 pieces then go with server controls and assign the innerHTML from your code behind.. dont forget to mark my answer as the right one

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but Ryan McDonough gave me the right answer first this time.