# Trying to read items from a DataTable into a webpage

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to read items from a DataTable into a webpage, but getting 2 errors in the C# code: `p1.InnerHTML = dt.rows(0).Item(0);`

Errors:

p1 does not exist in the current content.
System.Data.Datatable does not contain a definition for 'rows' and no extension method 'rows' accepting a first argument ..

C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string strConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ChinatowndbConnString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
    string sql = "SELECT pagetext FROM Content where pagetag = 1";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    sd.Fill(dt);

    p1.InnerHTML = dt.rows(0).Item(0);
    p2.InnerHTML = dt.rows(1).Item(0);
    p3.InnerHTML = dt.rows(2).Item(0);
}
```

HTML:

```
<p id="p1" class="none"></p>
<p id="p2" class="none"></p>
<p id="p3" class="none"></p>
```

Any ideas how to get my code working,

Thanks
Tea

Comment: In c#, array syntax uses brackets instead of parentheses. `dt.Rows[0].Item[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `p` is a html element, you must add `runat=server` if you want to access it on serverside
2. C# is case-sensitive and the property is called `Rows` instead of `rows`

   ```
   <p id="p1" runat="server" class="none"></p>
   <p id="p2" runat="server" class="none"></p>
   <p id="p3" runat="server" class="none"></p>
   ```

Furthermore, in C# an arry indexer is accessed via square brackets instead of parentheses. But i would suggest to use the [`DataRow.Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) extension method instead:

```
p1.InnerHtml = dt.Rows[0].Field<String>(0); // first field of first row, assuming that it's a string
```

Final note: you have also mispelled `InnerHtml`. Visual Studio can correct it automatically for you if the cursor is somewhere in  `InnerHTML` and you press <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd>.

Comment: There is no such thing as `Item` and in c sharp you have to use [] instead of ().

Comment: @Kaf: Changed to use strongly typed `Field`  extension.

Comment: InnerHTML giving an error: System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl' does not contain a definition for 'InnerHTML' and no extension method 'InnerHTML' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @TeaDrinkingGeek: Edited my answer, you have also "miscased" `InnerHtml` with `InnerHTML`. Visual Studio will correct it automatically for you if the cursor is somewhere in  InnerHTML and you press `Ctrl+Space`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add runat="server" for each of them to be accessible on server side.

```
<p id="p1" class="none" runat="server"></p>
<p id="p2" class="none" runat="server"></p>
<p id="p3" class="none" runat="server"></p>
```

and when assigning use

```
dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
dt.Rows[1][0].ToString();
dt.Rows[2][0].ToString();
```